# How to get around for loop bottleneck for constant time operations?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, time-complexity

Working on a rules agnostic poker simulator for fun. Testing bottlenecks in enumeration, and for hands that would always get pulled from the "unique" array, I found an interesting bottleneck. I measured the average computation time of running each of the variations below 1,000,000,000 times and then took the best of 100 repetitions of that to allow JIT and Hotspot to work their magic. What I found was there's a difference in computation time (6ns vs 27ns) between

```
public int getRank7(int ... cards) {
  int q = (cards[0] >> 16) | (cards[1] >> 16) | (cards[2] >> 16) | (cards[3] >> 16) | (cards[4] >> 16) | (cards[5] >> 16) | (cards[6] >> 16);
  int product = ((cards[0] & 0xFF) * (cards[1] & 0xFF) * (cards[2] & 0xFF) * (cards[3] & 0xFF) * (cards[4] & 0xFF) * (cards[5] & 0xFF) * (cards[6] & 0xFF));
  if(flushes[q] > 0) return flushes[q];
  if(unique[q] > 0) return unique[q];
  int x = Arrays.binarySearch(products, product);
  return rankings[x];
}
```

and

```
public int getRank(int ... cards) {
  int q = 0;
  long product = 1;
  for(int c : cards) {
    q |= (c >> 16);
    product *= (c & 0xFF);
  }
  if(flushes[q] > 0) return flushes[q];
  if(unique[q] > 0) return unique[q];
  int x = Arrays.binarySearch(products, product);
  return rankings[x];
}
```

The issue is definitely the for loop, not the addition of handling multiplication at the top of the function. I'm a little baffled by this since I'm running the same number of operations in each scenario... I realized I'd always have 6 or more cards in this function so I brought things closer together by changing it to

```
public int getRank(int c0, int c1, int c2, int c3, int c4, int c5, int ... cards)
```

But I'm going to have the same bottleneck as the number of cards goes up. Is there any way to get around this fact, and if not, could somebody explain to me why a for loop for the same number of operations is so much slower?

Comment: Actually, you're not running the same number of operations in each scenario. In the first example, you skip the multiplication if `flushes[q] > 0` or if `unique[q] > 0`. In the second example, you always do the multiply. You're certain that doesn't make a difference in the timings?

Comment: Positive. I've tested it with multiplication removed completely, which had no change in runtime. Moving it after the check to unique just adds the overhead of an additional for loop for every pair/two-pair/set/boat/quad type hand. 

Just as a proof of concept that it's some hidden aspect of loop logic in general as opposed to one of the operations defined in loop itself, I moved every variable used in it (x & cards.length) to method parameters which had no change, and also tried switching from cards.length to a static variable neither again with no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll find that the big difference is branching. Your for loop scenario requires a check and conditional branch on each iteration of the for loop. Your CPU will try and predict which branch will be taken, and pipeline instructions accordingly, but when it mispredicts (at least once per function call, as the loop terminates), the pipeline stalls, which is very expensive.

One thing to try would be a regular for loop with a fixed upper bound (rather than one based on the length of the array); the Java JRE may unroll such a loop, which would result in the same sequence of operations as your more efficient version.

Comment: I will definitely look more into branching. As for your suggestion on switching to a regular for loop, the best I can do is change it to an instance variable, or a method parameter neither of which seemed to have any effect - is there anything else I should try? 


Thank you for your explanation on branching, the main reason I'm writing this program is to learn more about time complexity and bottlenecks. Is there anywhere you could point me for some solid information on the actual steps the machine takes, and why it impacts performance? Would I get the same impact with 7 if statements?

Comment: @sgrif What I was suggesting is to try an actual constant - in this case, '7'. If it speeds up, you know it's because the JIT unrolled your loop, and the slowdown was due to branching. If it doesn't, it may still be branching - but the JIT may not be smart enough to unroll the loop. For more about branch (mis)prediction, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor

Comment: And yes, if statements would be just as bad - the cost is when the CPU guesses wrong about which branch the code will take. If you're really into optimizing, the best approach will likely be to either write hardcoded evaluators for each hand type, or write some code that generates bytecode and JITs it at runtime.

Comment: Can't use a hard coded constant. Tried it just to see if there was a performance difference. Ran 23ns, so it improved it slightly. 

As for hard coding each type of hand, that's definitely the best way to ensure things are optimized, but more or less defeats the purpose of writing it. Only thing I'm hard coding is optimizations for 5 cards since that is needed regardless. As for generating bytecode and JITing it at runtime... There's actually a few places that would be really useful to me. This just opened another can of worms. XD

Comment: @sgrif You can't use a hard coded constant because you want it to be variable? I was only suggesting it for testing purposes - clearly your first function is hard coded to only work with 7 cards. :)

Comment: Another thing to try would be to use a debugger to examine the generated bytecode and native code for each function. Possibly you could use a low level profiler to see where the time's being spent, too.

Comment: Like I said, I tried it to test. :) I assume the eclipse debugger is not capable of doing that? (I've also failed to figure out how to get it to profile things as well... Very inexperienced with Java, I miss VIM...)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10771/discussion-between-sgrif-and-nick-johnson)

Comment: As for resources about machine steps, most (all?) CS departments have courses in computer architecture, which is what this is about. We used the book *Computer Organization and Design* by Patterson & Hennessy which among other things teaches the basics about the CPU and pipelining.

Answer (score 0):

That enhanced `for` loop requires setting up an iterator, which is relatively expensive when you only have a handful of items.

It'd be interesting to see what your timings are if you wrote a traditional `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; ++i)
{
    q |= (cards[i] >> 16);
    product *= (cards[i] & 0xFF);
}
```

But even that is likely to be slightly slower than the first example, because there's some loop overhead (incrementing the index, comparing it against the length, and branching to the beginning of the loop).

In any case, the loop overhead adds an increment, a comparison, and a branch to each iteration. And that comparison could very well require a pointer de-reference to get to `cards.length`. It's quite plausible that the loop overhead is much more expensive than the work you're doing in the loop.

Comment: Tried that before I posted - there was no measurable change in timing.

Comment: What if you do a "int N = cards.length" prior to the for loop, then use N rather than cards.length as the loop guard?  Otherwise you have to dereference the cards object every pass through the loop, to find the length.

Comment: Just tried your change, Heath. Moved init of x to the top as well. "int q=0, i=cards.length, x=0;" - Didn't seem to have any effect. To my knowledge, JVM is smart enough to make micro-optimizations like that on it's own.

Comment: Jim, could you elaborate a bit more on your explanation as to why the for loop adds such massive overhead? None of those steps should take even a single ns even when run billions of times.

Comment: Of course those steps are going to take time. Incrementing `i` requires a fetch, increment, store (unless it's kept in a register). Comparing `i` with `cards.length` requires time, as does branching to the start of the loop. Even at 2 GHz, loop overhead is going to cost at least a nanosecond per iteration.